# Post same objectID in to different table

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm trying to post a data in my user then at the same time, post the _id of my user as a reference id in my donation table.

After I posted my data in the users table like this:

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var Blooddonation = require('../models/blooddonation'); 
router.post('/createBlooduser',function(req, res) {

        var user = new User(); 

        user.user_lastname =  req.body.user_lastname;
        user.status= "initial";
        user.save(function(err) {});
    });
```

How can I get the _id of the posted data and make a reference id in my donation table? Something like this:

```
**users.json**
{
_id:ObjectId("5c7e591eee959272cc5768cb"),
user_lastname:"Jhonson",
status:"initial"
}

**blooddonations.json**
{
donor_id:ObjectId("5c7e591eee959272cc5768cb")
}
```

Comment: `user._id`. It was actually populated with a value as soon as you did `new User()`. Basically write your `Bloodonation` data **inside** the callback from `user.save()`

Comment: can you make a clearer solution mate? im having a hard time here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_id` property is actually created as soon as you create new instance with a statement like `new User()`. So you can actually access that value *before* it's even stored in the collection, or at any time after instance creation really:

```
router.post('/createBlooduser',function(req, res) {

    var user = new User(); 

    user.user_lastname =  req.body.user_lastname;
    user.status= "initial";
    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;  // or really handle better

      // You can also just create() rather than new Blooddonation({ donor_id: user._id })
      Blooddonation.create({ donor_id: user._id }, function(err, donor) {
         // check for errors and/or respond
      })
    });
});
```

Of if you might just want access to other properties that might "default on save", then you can access in the callback from `save()` or `create()`:

```
router.post('/createBlooduser',function(req, res) {

    User.create({
      user_lastname: req.body.user_lastname;
      status: "initial"
    }, function(err, user) {       // this time we pass from the callback
      if (err) throw err;          // or really handle better

      Blooddonation.create({ donor_id: user._id }, function(err, donor) {
         // check for errors and/or respond
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't post to my database,There is no error response and I dont know what's wrong

Comment: thanks! I was silly, there is required item, that's why it's not inserting